# Asp ČŠŽ to CSZ not working

Tags: asp-classic, special-characters

I get the string from input through post option an function

```
Replace(string, "Č", "C")
```

not working, becouse function doesen't recognise 'Č' char from variable( Request.Form("folder")).

I use for loop and this function to get char from string

```
strChar = mid(someString,i,1)
```

I could use

```
If Asc(strChar) = -15220  Then  'Č
   string = string + "C"
```

but doesent always work. I think becouse 'Č' some how, use more than one char if using mid() function.

Is any other solution?

Comment: You might want to start with [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Put this one on your ASP code:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

And in your HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Remove AddHeader its duplicating the function of ContentType and CharSet properties.  The meta tag is overkill that tag is really only necessary when opening a htm from the file system since otherwise the browser will have access the actual `Content-Type` header in the response.